# How can add an icon to array list

Tags: android, arraylist

I have two class main and datos.

In datos i have 3 attributes:

```
nombre;---> the name of the team
 imagen;--->logo of the team
 web;--->and team webpage
```

Datos class:

```
public class Datos {
    private String nombre, website;
    private int imagen;

    public Datos(String nombre, String website, int imagen) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.website = website;
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }

    public int getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }

    public void setImagen(int imagen) {
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }


}
```

Main:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        cargaspinner();
    }

    public void cargaspinner(){
        ArrayList<datos> datosArrayList = new ArrayList<datos>();
        datosArrayList.add(new datos("Barcelona", barcelona.com, ??));
        ArrayAdapter<datos> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, datosArrayList);
        spinner.asetAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

[main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T66W.png)
[datos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpa54.png)

Comment: show the code of your datos class....and also the name of the class should start with a capital letter. rename your method cargasspinner to cargasSpinner....learn to write down properly java code

Comment: public class datos {

    String nombre;
    Icon   imagen;
    String web;

    public datos(String nombre, Icon imagen, String web) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.imagen = imagen;
        this.web = web;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Icon getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }

    public void setImagen(Icon imagen) {
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }

    public String getWeb() {
        return web;
    }


    }
}

Comment: add it in your post properly formatted

Comment: do you import the logo from drawable or mipmap folder or from the internet?

Comment: @SergioHr Add the error in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Icons/drawable are basically `int` in android so you can declare list of images/icons as follows:

```
List<Integer> icons = new ArrayList<>();

icons.add(R.drawable.icon1);
icons.add(R.drawable.icon2);
```

Comment below if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

So you have to modify the method like this:

```
public void cargaspinner(){
        ArrayList<Datos> datosArrayList = new ArrayList<Datos>();
        datosArrayList.add(new Datos("Barcelona", "http://www.barcelona.com", R.drawable.image));
        ArrayAdapter<Datos> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, datosArrayList);
        spinner.asetAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: [here the error][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/W8w5y.png


i don't know why... thx u for help me

Comment: of course you will have errors...take the Datos class as it is in your question and delete yours